# Make GIT warn me about composer.lock change if I do "git checkout" or "git pull"

Tags: git, composer-php

How could I make GIT warn me about composer.lock change if I do "git checkout" or "git pull"?

Is there any ready-to-use solution for this? Or maybe a ready-to-use GIT hook?

Is this useful? Or is it a bad idea to have such functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found the solution, so i've decided to to write it on my own - https://github.com/bfday/php-git-hooks

Not very flexible but my problem solved.
If u find more interesting solution - let me know.